# How to post array to php using ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Bagaimana cara mengirim data dari array ke controller pada sebuah php? aku sudah mencoba menggunakan ajax. tapi hasil mengeluarkan ErrorException
Undefined index: genres.

This My Js

```
function publish(){
var genres = ["Romance", "Drama", "History"];
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/movies/stores",
    dataType:"json",
    data: {'genres' : JSON.stringify(genres)},
    contentType: "json",
});
}
```

this my controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
       $input = $request->all();
       $genres = ($_POST['genres']);
       dd($genres);
       dd($input);
    }
```

my route

```
Route::post('/admin/movies/stores', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store')->name('store');
```

Answer (score 0):

When posting arrays to PHP, you use `[]`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/movies/stores",
    dataType:"json",
    data: {'genres[]' : genres},
    // contentType: "json", not json
});
```